# A call to PInvoke function '[...]' has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

I'm getting this weird error on some stuff I've been using for quite a while. It may be a new thing in Visual Studio 2010 but I'm not sure.
I'm trying to call a unamanged function written in C++ from C#.
From what I've read on the internet and the error message itself it's got something to do with the fact that the signature in my C# file is not the same as the one from C++ but I really can't see it.
First of all this is my unamanged function below:

```
TEngine GCreateEngine(int width,int height,int depth,int deviceType);
```

And here is my function in C#:

```
[DllImport("Engine.dll", EntryPoint = "GCreateEngine", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
        public static extern IntPtr CreateEngine(int width,int height,int depth,int device);
```

When I debug into C++ I see all arguments just fine so thus I can only think it's got something to do with transforming from TEngine (which is a pointer to a class named CEngine) to IntPtr. I've used this before in VS2008 with no problem.

Comment: Hi all, I am facing same issue but with Visual studio 2013. I have directly added reference of c++ dll to my c# project that was working fine in 2010 but not in 2013. I have also mentioned CallingConvention.Cdecl

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe the problem lies in the calling convention. Are you sure the unmanaged function was compiled as stdcall and not something else ( i would guess fastcall ) ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand that. I compiled exactly as I said on my question. I didn't add any __std or anything like that. Before it worked very well without it.
EDIT: but now apparently adding __std in the function prototype and declaration fixes it. Thanks

Comment: Had this exact problem - I had assumed declspec(dllexport) made them stdcall for some reason, but that was not the case.  Changing my DLL's calling convention to explicitly specify the calling convention (and then specifying in C# too) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 99):

I had a _cdecl c++ dll that I called without any trouble from Visual Studio 2008, and then the identical code in Visual Studio 2010 would not work. I got the same PInvoke ... has unbalanced the stack error as well.

The solution for me was to specify the calling convention in the DllImport(...) attribute:
From:

```
[DllImport(CudaLibDir)]
```

To:

```
[DllImport(CudaLibDir, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

I guess they changed the default calling convention for DLLImport between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 50):

It could also be that in the .NET Framework version 3.5, the pInvokeStackImbalance MDA is disabled by default. Under 4.0 (or maybe VS2010) it is [enabled by default](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/csharplanguage/thread/ef65cd89-d40e-400a-a9b0-3b625e3d22fe).

> Yes. Technically, the code was always wrong, and previous versions of
>   the framework silently corrected it.
>
> To quote the [.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656%28v=VS.100%29.aspx): "To improve
>   performance in interoperability with unmanaged code, incorrect calling
>   conventions in a platform invoke now cause the application to fail. In
>   previous versions, the marshaling layer resolved these errors up the
>   stack... If you have binaries that cannot be updated, you can include
>   the <[NetFx40_PInvokeStackResilience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361650%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)> element in your application's configuration file to enable calling
>   errors to be resolved up the stack as in earlier versions. However,
>   this may affect the performance of your application."

An easy way to fix this is to specify the calling convention and make sure it is the same as in the DLL. A `__declspec(dllexport)` should yield a *cdecl* format.

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code, if say your DLL has the name **MyDLL.dll** and you want to use the function **MyFunction** within the Dll

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void MyFunction();
```

this worked for me.

Comment: What did you do differently here? Why did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case (VB 2010 and DLL compiled with Intel Fortran 2011 XE) the problem exists when my application targets .NET Framework 4. If I change targeted framework to version 3.5, then everything works fine as expected.
So, I would guess the reason is something introduced in .Net Framework 4 but I have no idea at the moment which one

Update: The problem was solved by recompiling Fortran DLL and explicitly specifying STDCALL as calling convention for export names in the DLL.