# P/Invoke in C#, how to find out CallingConvention?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I updated my project from VS2005 (targeting .net 2) to VS2010 (targeting .net4). It seems the [pInvokeStackImbalance MDA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768223/166286) is enabled by default, then I get a bunch of `"unbalanced the stack"` exceptions. Take this one for example:

```
[DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(BrushStyles enBrushStyle, int crColor);
```

It was working in .net 2 but now it throws exception. I changed it to this and it works:

```
[DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(BrushStyles enBrushStyle, int crColor);
```

To my surprise, [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/CreateSolidBrush.html) lists it as

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(uint crColor);
```

Why my old is not working? It seems the pinvoke.net is wrong but how do I find out which calling conversion is it given a win32 function?

**EDIT**
My project is using the code from [C# Rubber Rectangle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27389/C-Rubber-Rectangle) to do the XOR drawing. Apparently the code needs a fix to work in .Net 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CreateSolidBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183518.aspx) uses `stdcall`. Almost all Win32 APIs do so. They never use `thiscall`. The function is declared as:

```
HBRUSH CreateSolidBrush(
  __in  COLORREF crColor
);
```

so your mistake is simply that your version has too many parameters. The pinvoke.net declaration that you have found is correct.

The `stdcall` convention pushes params right to left which explains how your code worked even with an extra spurious parameter.

Comment: How do you know it's `stdcall`? The link doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: API functions always are. If you look it up in the header file you'll see it declared as `WINAPI` which evaluates to `__stdcall`. A very small number are `__cdecl` because they have variable number of arguments. For example [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx). The API docs will always explicitly call out a `__cdecl` API function.

Comment: Thanks! Cannot believe the method signature was wrong all the time!!

Comment: Obviously the `enBrushStyle` parameter you were passing was being ignored. One can only wonder at where your version came from!  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, they got it wrong. Of course, it should be obvious seeing that the function is called Create**Solid**Brush. The style is part of the name. Anyway, it's all clear now.

Comment: The OP forgot to mention he ran his code on the 64-bit version of Windows.  The default platform target got changed in VS2010.

Comment: Yes it's in 64bit win7. What do you mean the default platform target got changed?