# Using DllImport on class library

Tags: c#, dllimport

I use dllimport method (PrintBarcode) in c# on a class library's method().

```
[DllImport(BXLDIR, SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "PrinterOpen", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern Int32 PrinterOpen(string strPort, Int32 lTimeout);


public static bool PrintOrderNoInfos(string orderNo, string printerIP)
{
      var infos = GetInfosByOrderNo(orderNo).FirstOrDefault();
      var printerOutPortName = String.Format("ETH{0}:9100", printerIP);
      BXLModule.PrinterOpen(printerOutPortName, 1000);
}
```

Then i reference this class lib dll on presentation layer and when i call this method (PrintOrderNoInfos)

```
 var res = OrderInfosHelper.PrintOrderNoInfos("2100022127000700", "20.10.15.58");
```

an error occurs like

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'InfosByOrderNoLibrary!InfosByOrderNoLibrary.BxlPrint::PrinterOpen'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message tells what you should do: “*Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.”*

Comment: If you find that [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941960/a-call-to-pinvoke-function-has-unbalanced-the-stack) did not solve your problem make sure to update the question with results of your investigation so it can be re-opened. Make sure to include signature of native method into the post.

Comment: Without the declaration of the unmanaged function, nobody can say more than the error message. Who knows, perhaps you got confused between `PrinterOpen` and `PrintBarcode`.